# GeoPandas fails silently when reading GeoJSONs

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, ogr, fiona

I have a file `example.geojson`. This file has 68 features ([`jq '.features | length' example.geojson`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/447988/191643) returns 68).

---

If I try to load this file to a GeoPandas dataframe ([`gpd.read_file` docs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html)), I can choose from 2 engines:

> **engine : str, “fiona”: or “pyogrio”** The underlying library that is used to read the file. Currently, the supported options are “fiona”
> and “pyogrio”. Defaults to “fiona” if installed, otherwise tries
> “pyogrio”.

Attempt using `fiona`:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df_fiona = gpd.read_file("example.geojson", engine="fiona")
```

I get a dataframe with 45 rows (`len(df_fiona)`).

---

Attempt using `pyogrio`:

```
df_pyogrio = gpd.read_file("example.geojson", engine="pyogrio")
```

This returns:

```
ERROR 1: GeoJSON object too complex, please see the OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE environment option
ERROR 1: GeoJSON object too complex, please see the OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE environment option
# ... many rows like this ...
ERROR 1: GeoJSON object too complex, please see the OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE environment option
ERROR 1: GeoJSON object too complex, please see the OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE environment option
More than 1000 errors or warnings have been reported. No more will be reported from now.
```

`len(df_pyogrio)` is still 45.

---

I can solve this problem and read in 68 features by:

```
import fiona
with fiona.Env(OGR_GEOJSON_MAX_OBJ_SIZE="1000MB"):
    df_fiona_env = gpd.read_file("example.geojson", engine="fiona")
```

Now `len(df_fiona_env)` is 68, as expected.

---

I wouldn't have found this out if I did not check if number of features matches with the number of rows in my GeoDataFrame. If I do not specify the engine `df = gpd.read_file("example.geojson")`, behaviour is the same as if engine was set to `fiona` explicitly (as expected from the [docs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html), "*[d]efaults to “fiona” if installed, otherwise tries “pyogrio”.*")

I think it would be much better if `gpd.read_file` would throw an error if it cannot read the whole file, rather than failing silently.

How can I make `gpd.read_file` (or for that matter, any other GeoPandas function) throw an error if it fails?

---

To me this seems like a bug, and maybe I should open an issue [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues) or [here](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues). I'd like to know if I'm wrong, or if there is an easier way to handle this issue.

My versions:

`gpd.__version__`: `0.12.2`, `fiona.__version__`: `1.8.22`, `from platform import python_version; print(python_version())`: `3.10.6`

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427301/python-error-handling-opening-a-shapefile-with-fiona, it may help.

Comment: Do you mean `df_pyogrio = gpd.read_file("example.geojson", engine="pyogrio")` where you wrote `df_pyogrio = gpd.read_file("example.geojson", engine="fiona")`?

Comment: Yes, good catch. Correcting it.